# How to get order information on the checkout complete page?

Tags: 7, commerce

How do you get the order information such as user's name, address, e-mail and products he ordered, on the checkout complete page on Drupal Commerce for Drupal 7?

Comment: This might help
http://theoleschool.com/blog/templating-commerce-order-completion-pane/

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to complete this task.
First, you must get the order id from session or database using query.
Second, you must create an $order object like this

```
$order = commerce_order_load($orderId);
```

Define a new order sdtClass

```
$myOrder = new stdClass();
```

Wrap the order

```
$orderWrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
```

And then you can get various order info like this:

```
// Get order number
$orderNumber = $order->order_number;

// Get user's e-mail address and encode properly encode it
$orderMail = drupal_json_encode($user->mail);

// Prepare an array to store products
$orderPurchasedItems = array();
// Create a foreach to loop through all the products and get the products info
foreach ($items as $item) {
    // Checks if the value is equal to product
    if ($item->type->value() === 'product') {
        // Get the unit price value per product
        $commerceUnitPrice = $item->commerce_unit_price->value();
        $entity = $item->value();
        if ($entity) {
            $orderPurchasedItems[] = array(
                "id" => $entity->nid,
                "quantity" => $item->quantity->value(),
                "price" => commerce_currency_format(
                    $commerceUnitPrice['amount'],
                    $commerceUnitPrice['currency_code']
                ), // this will result in $10
            );
            // Store all the ordered products in a new variable so we can use it later
            $myOrderProducts = $orderPurchasedItems;
        }
    }
}
```